# Jinja return elements of list with ''

Tags: flask, jinja2

I pass into Jinja template tuple. For example `('Super post', 'helo gelo everybody', ['tag', 'tag2'])`
Jinja show the first and second elements of tuple well (without '' on both ends). But when I start to iter elements of list, I get elements like `'tag'` and `'tag2'`.

```
 {% for poster in post %}
        <div class="blo">
         <h1>{{ poster[0] }}</h1>{{ poster[1] }}
                <div class="sashacom" >
                    {% for item in poster[2] %}
                    {{ item }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I pass to rendering result of this function:

```
def get_posts_index(PAGE):
    for posts in p.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).slice(start=POSTS_PER_PAGE*(PAGE-1),stop=POSTS_PER_PAGE*PAGE):
        yield (posts.title, posts.body, t.query.filter(Tag.post.any(id=posts.id)).all())
```

I attempt to print result before rendering, it's ok.

```
for p in get_posts_index(1):
    print (p)

('post', 'rgsaergsaegr', ['dgdfg', 'dfgdfg', 'uy'])
('Super post', 'helo gelo everybody', ['tag', 'tug'])
```

Comment: How are you rendering this? When I attempt to reproduce this everything comes out fine:
`template.render(post=(('Post1', 'Data1', ['tag1', 'tag2']), ('Post2', 'Data2', ['tag1', 'tag2'])))`

Comment: Simply ` return render_template('index.html',
            paginate=paginate,
            title = 'Simple blog on Flask',
            post = posts.get_posts_index(page),
            tag = posts.get_tags_index())`

Comment: I would print your `post` tuple before you render to make sure you don't have escaped single quotes in your object.

Comment: I added my answer to the topic